# Не удается найти часть пути к файлу

Tags: c#, xmlparser

Есть проект библиотеки в котором необхдимо хранить `XML` файл.
Структура такова:

```
 --libray_root
  |Resources
   --codes.xml
  |Logic
   --Iso4217.cs
```

Файл логики:

```
public static class Iso4217Codes
    {
        private static List<Currency> Codes { get; set; }
        private const string codesPath = @"..\Resources\codes.xml";

        public static long LoadingSpent { get; }

        static Iso4217Codes()
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();

            LoadXml();

            timer.Stop();
            LoadingSpent = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        public static void LoadXml()
        {
            var document = XElement.Load(codesPath);

            Codes = (from node in document.Descendants("CcyNtry")
                     select new Currency
                     {
                         Country = node.XPathSelectElement("CtryNm")?.Value,
                         Symbol = node.XPathSelectElement("Ccy")?.Value,
                         Name = node.XPathSelectElement("CcyNm")?.Value,
                         Code = node.XPathSelectElement("CcyNbr")?.Value
                     }).ToList();

        }

        public static string GetSimbolByCode(int code)
        {
            return Codes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == code.ToString())?.Symbol;
        }

        public static string GetCurrencyNameByCode(int code)
        {
            return Codes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == code.ToString())?.Name;
        }
    }
```

Создаю консольное приложение и портирую в него эту библиотеку для проверки работоспособности. При запуске получаю ошибку в пути к файлу.

Comment: А файл-то на месте или нет?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov файл на месте.

Comment: Укажите прямой путь к файлу. А потом разбирайтесь почему не работает косвенный путь. Проверьте что даёт ф-ция получения текущего каталога... и думаю ответ будет очевиден.

Comment: Приложение, кстати, ничего не знает про то, по какому пути находится cs. Что б узнать где cs, нужно помучатся с debuginfo. Обычно текущий путь совпадает с расположением exe-модуля, который запущен (если в параметрах запуска не указано другое). А если у вас IIS то текущий путь - другой, а если у вас какая-то либа для nuget то текущий путь может быть ещё другой. Если вас интерисуте путь относительно конкретного модуля - то берете assembly от модуля, находите её FullPath оттуда берете путь и комбинируете. Поэтому указанного вами "дерева" файлов, не достаточно что бы понять где у вас ошибка.

Comment: Через assembly путь получить можно так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854338/getting-current-directory-in-windows-ce-5-0-using-c-sharp-compact-2-0 В вашем случае `typeof(Iso4217Codes).Assembly.GetName().CodeBase`

Comment: Попробуйте  `@".\Resources\codes.xml"`

Comment: Относительный путь отсчитывается от текущей папки приложения, а не библиотеки. Создайте программно (например, с помощью `File.Create`) файл по пути `@"..\Resources\test.xml"` и посмотрите, где он окажется. | Вернее, посмотрите в исключении на получившийся путь.

Comment: Выходит, что за точку отсчета берется место расположения екзешника консольного приложения, к которому я подключил данную либу и следовательно поиск идет в приложении а не в либе. Тогда вытекает вопрос как сделать, чтоб поиск пути был внутри либы. Вариант с `typeof(Iso4217Codes).Assembly.GetName().CodeBase` дает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 1):

"внутри либы" с точки зрения .net не существует. Исходники компилируются в dll/exe, и где именно исходники лежали изначально - несущественно.

Вам придется, на выбор:

- Копировать этот файл в папку к exe (руками, или через свойство Copy to output folder для этого файла проекте)
- Вшивать файл внутрь exe / dll, поменяв ему compilation type с Content на Embedded Resource и доставать его в рантайме через `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`.